# Cannot Start Weblogic Managed Server,

Tags: weblogic

We are running Weblogic 7sp6.  We have a working single node cluster with an Admin and two Managed servers.  We are re-creating a 2nd standalone cluster on a 2nd server.  We reinstalled Weblogic and have copied over all the configuration files to make thing.  Its the same on both clusters.  We changed all the references to IP and hostnames. We have used this method before without problems.

In the current case I can startup the Admin which listens on port 7001,7002.  But when I try and startup either of the Managed servers it tells me that myserver1/2 is already up.  (Managed Servers).  I confirmed that myserver is configured to use port 7012,7013 and I cannot find any port conflicts especially because these exact ports worked on the first cluster.  Any ideas of what else to look at?  I have logged in the admin console and can see the ports are all unique.  Thanks

Comment: There must be a configuration mistake somewhere and without seeing the config.xml, the logs, a trace, the command line, etc it seems hard to say anything. I also second duffy's answser, using WLS 7 (an intermediate version) in 2010 sounds weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current version of WebLogic is 10.3.  I'd strongly urge you to upgrade your WebLogic as soon as possible, especially if you're still using the version of JDK that it was certified for.   If you're running JDK 1.4, you're crazy.

Comment: Thanks guys, it was the StartManagedWeblogic.cmd, it had the IP of the first cluster for the Admin IP.  

Also understand the version issues, not my call this is a client site and they understand the risks and don't want to upgrade now.